# Django form processing

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm during the form tutorial on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/. I'm trying to make a simple form element, which will be POSTing some data. This is function launched in urls.py:

```
def get_name(request):
# if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
if request.method == 'POST':
    # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
    form = NameForm(request.POST)
    # check whether it's valid:
    if form.is_valid():
        # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
        # ...
        # redirect to a new URL:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

# if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
else:
    form = NameForm()

return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

HTML code looks as follows:

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When I input some data to form and click 'Submit' button, function connected to /your-name/ URL is launched and I'm redirected to /your-name/. I'm wondering why function connected to /thanks/ URL is not launching. How can it be reached?

Comment: You have spelling errors and I don't see or understand your problem.

Comment: What? You've set your form to point to /your-name/, so of course that's the URL that's going to be called. If you want to call /thanks/, you should point it to that.

Comment: Ok, but when function form.is_valid() will be launched and HTTP redirection performed?

Answer (score 0):

For the view to work, the form's action `/your-name/` must be served by your view `get_name`.

You haven't shown your url patterns, so it's impossible to tell whether the mistake is there or not.